# Rails で link_to の使用時、コントローラへ値を渡すには

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails で view から controller へ値の受け渡しの実装したいと考えております。

現在、view で以下のように記述しております。

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', some_path(edit: some.id) %>
```

しかしながら、上記では url にパラメータが含まれてしまいます。

url にパラメータを含めず、view から controller へ値の受け渡しを
することは可能でしょうか。可能であれば、どのように記述すればよろしいでしょうか。

ご教授いただけますと、幸いです。

Comment: 生成されるURLの具体的な例について、現状と希望を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: `rails routes`で定義されている一覧に`edit_some_path`はありませんか？`some_path`ってID渡すと思うんだけど...`some_path`にパラメータ渡すとどんなURLが生成されますか？パラメータを渡さないとどんなURLが生成されますか？可能であれば`rails routes`から対象の部分を切り出して記載するとより良い回答が得られると思います。

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb で`:edit` を含んだパターンのルーティングを定義すればパラメータ(query string)として付く代わりにURLの一部に入るように出来ますが、そもそも今回やりたいことは`edit_some_path` を使えないケースなのでしょうか?